# New revision isn't created when saving model

Tags: django, django-reversion

I use [Reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) to control changes in model objects. In [documentation](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#creating-revisions) I've found this:

> Whenever you call save() on a model within the scope of a revision, it
>   will be added to that revision

Here's my code where I use model's save method:

```
c.save(update_fields=['status'])
```

When this code is executed there is no new record in revisions list of the object, at least I don't see it in the admin.

Comment: Same for me. The update is recorded in the database but not added into the "revision" table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem where edits made in the admin interface had reversions, but those in the shell did not.

@yilmazhuseyin is correct, you need the context wrapper, but I found I had an additional bug that my models weren't getting registered.

In `admin.py`:

```
class YourModelAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

will register your model, but only if the admin code is called. It wasn't being called when I invoked the shell via `python manage.py shell`

So, to fix this I added to `models.py`

```
import reversion
reversion.register(YourModel)
```

And then when I saved an object, I still needed to use the context wrapper

```
 with reversion.create_revision():
     obj.save()
```

**Update:**

Revision has a few tips for this situation. (http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#api) One is to simply import your admin module so that the revision gets called.

Comment: You should not need to register the model a second time if you have already registered it in the admin. http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#api

Comment: Agreed. The problem arises if the admin code is not imported. Note the first warning on the page you've referenced. I will update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save model in revision transaction.

Note: If you call save() outside of the scope of a revision, a revision is NOT created. This means that you are in control of when to create revisions.

Source: http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#creating-revisions